# Create IndexSearcher is throwing IOException read past EOF

Tags: java, lucene

When I try to to  create an object of `new IndexSearcher(fsDir)` class it is throwing `IOException read past EOF`. The search index is not RAM based, it is NFS based (used `FSDirectory` lucene class).

I googled and got that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620422/lucene-search-error-stack) one

There is not permission issue, neither locked, I checked with [lockhunter](http://lockhunter.com/)

So there must be write permission and none is using that directory.

It was working the past 2-3 months. Yesterday suddenly stopped working, all indexed files in the folder.

What else may cause to this exception? Is there something like if index is 2-3 month old (some period), then it gets expired and gives this exception?

Comment: I rebuild the index, then worked (took 2 hours), but still did not get why it sis not work before, after rebuild file size is the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer, spending a lot of time on it, It will give that exception(IOException read past EOF):

```
If Directory does not give write permission
If someone else is using(locked)
If some segment is corrupted
```

For my case It was corrupted :(. But Exception does not say anything about this(Could tell some `FIleCurroptedException`). This is may help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I got this, it had two index files (record) with same name (key - i am using mongo-lucene). I deleted the one of the record with empty buffer and it let me go forward without having to re-build the entire index. This seems like a multi-thread issue. Another trigger seem to be indexing non-text files